# converting the glmer output from logit to response scale

Tags: r, regression, glm, lme4, emmeans

I hoping get some can help solving this mystery in my mind. The 7th coefficient in my `glmer()` call is 0.28779305 on the **logit** scale.

This coefficient can be also obtained by using `contrast()` in the `emmeans` package. However, this package apparently outputs the 7th coefficient on a different scale, the **response** scale.

I wonder how to convert the estimate given by the `contrast()` call so it matches the 7th coefficient in my `glmer()` call?

*ps. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886418/16762740) provides some insight but I don't see a way the coefficient from these two packages might be related.*

```r
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(broom.mixed)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fpqq/w/main/d.csv")

form2 <- y ~ item_type*time + (1 | user_id)

m2 <- glmer(form2, family = binomial, data = dat,
            control =
              glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))

coef(summary(m2))[7,]
#  Estimate Std. Error    z value   Pr(>|z|)   # This Estimate 
#0.28779305 0.11271202 2.55334842 0.01066927   # is on logit scale
#------------------------------------------------------------------
EMM <- emmeans(m2, ~ item_type * time)

CON <- list(c1 = c(1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0))

contrast(regrid(EMM), CON)
# contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value # This Estimate
# c1          0.106 0.0299 Inf 3.526   0.0004  # is on response scale
```

Comment: @BenBolker, good point, I will edit that, Thanks Ben.

Comment: @BenBolker, BTW, does my question make sense to you?

Comment: I think I know what's going on, but I'm hoping that the person who originally asked this question [on r-sig-mixed-models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2022q1/029968.html) will get it resolved there rather than spreading the conversation to another venue ...

Comment: @BenBolker, Ben `glmer` doesn't have a tag. So I used glmmtmb as a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line is that if you do

```
contrast(EMM, CON)
```

then maybe you'll get that coefficient you are asking about. That's assuming that the 7th coefficient is correctly identified.

The `EMM` object contains information about estimates of 8 different probabilities (call them p1, p2, ..., p8), on the logit scale.

- If you do `summary(EMM)`, you will get estimates of `logit(p1), logit(p2), ..., logit(p8)`.
- If you do `summary(EMM, type = "response")`, you will get estimates of `p1, p2, ..., p8`
- If you do `contrast(EMM, CON)` you will get an estimate of `logit(p1) - logit(p3) - logit(p5) + logit(p7) = log(o1) - log(o3) - log(o5) + log(o7)`, where `oj = pj / (1 - pj)` is the odds for the jth case.
- If you do `contrast(EMM, CON, type = "response")`, you get an estimate of `exp(log(o1) - log(o3) - log(o5) + log(o7)) = (o1*o7) / (o3*o5)`

Now, as documented, `REMM = regrid(EMM)` undoes the logit transformation once and for all. It preserves no memory of where it came from, it just has information about estimates on the response scale and their covariance matrix. Thus

- If you do `summary(REMM)`, you get estimates of `p1, p2, ..., p8`
- If you do `summary(REMM, type = "response")`, you get estimates of `p1, p2, ..., p8`. There is no transformation information in `REMM`, it is already on the response scale.
- If you do `contrast(REMM, CON)` (or `contrast(REMM, CON, type = "response")`), you get an estimate of `p1 - p3 - p5 + p7`.

The **emmeans** package documents all of this, and in addition contains several vignettes with examples. In particular, the one on [transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html) and the one on [comparisons and contrasts](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html) are especially pertinent here.

Comment: "Maybe" because it is not completely clear to me (largely because I didn't bother to think about it very much) that the coefficient is correctly identified as an estimate of that quantity.

Comment: There is a long history of unsuccessful attempts to answer this question before it ever got to SO. If my answer violates guidelines, I will happily remove it. But I have spent way too much time on this. And if my answer is inappropriate, then so is the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem inappropriate to me ... was there a now-deleted comment?

Comment: @BenBolker, Hi Ben, I suggested that Russ directly answer OP's specific question. Otherwise, I upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @RussLenth's answer:

- `contrast(EMM, CON)` gives you `log(o1) - log(o3) - log(o5) + log(o7)`, and it is indeed equal to the 7th coefficient value.
- `contrast(REMM, CON)` (i.e. regridded) gives you `p1 - p3 - p5 - p7`.

(where `oi` = odds in group i, `pi` = probability in group i, `oi = pi/(1-pi)`).

While it is possible to convert an individual log-odds value to a probability (if `loi` is the log-odds value, then `pi = 1/(1+exp(-loi))`), I don't think there's any way to convert a *linear combination* of log-odds values directly to the corresponding linear combination of probability values; instead, you'd have to do what `emmeans` is doing anyway — i.e., convert the individual log-odds values to the probability scale and then compute the linear combination. (In fact `emmeans` is going the other direction — computing the probabilities from the log-odds when you specify regridding.)

Your question also reveals a misunderstanding of what's going on here: you say

> apparently outputs the 7th coefficient on a different scale, the response scale

The package does **not** output the 7th coefficient on the response scale; instead, it applies the same contrast that would give the 7th coefficient on the log scale *to the group values on the probability scale*. "[T]he 7th coefficient on the response scale" would be

```
L(log(o1) - log(o3) - log(o5) + log(o7))
```

(where `L(x)` is the logistic function `1/(1+exp(-x))` [`plogis()` in R]). This is not the same as

```
L(log(o1)) - L(log(o3)) - L(log(o5)) + L(log(o7))
```

which is what `emmeans` gives you.

Comment: @morouzian, (1) I did answer the question in the first bullet point! (type = "link" is the default, so `contrast(EMM, CON)` does match the coefficient -- as I said. (2) It is almost always more sensible to test hypotheses on the link scale (where we can more confidently expect that the sampling distribution of the parameter vector will be MVN). AFAIK the OP is only interested in extracting the *value* of this contrast on the probability scale, for expository purposes. I would **not** advise testing the contrast on the probability scale.

Comment: It also depends on how you interpret "convert the estimate given by `contrast()`. I assumed that the OP wanted to convert the numerical value given by the regridded `emmeans` object back to the original scale; my answer explains why this is impossible.[

Comment: Maybe you could/should ask these questions on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ?